# Live streaming is not playing in videojs web player

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I am trying to play live tv channel streaming with videojs. live streaming is not playing but other videos are playing. Here is my all code. In html file there is given a live tv channel streaming m3u8 link. I want to stream this channel live in my web video player. what is the problem?

HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Responsive Video.js Example (v4.3)</title>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video.js"></script>
  <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf"
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Responsive Video.js Example (v4.3)</h1>
  <p></p>
  <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" data-setup='{ "asdf": true }' poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png">
        <source src="http://almonqith.tv:8134/hls-live/livepkgr/_definst_/livestream/livestream.m3u8" type='video/mp4'>
        <source src="http://almonqith.tv:8134/hds-live/livepkgr/_definst_/livestream/livestream.f4m" type='video/mp4'>
      </video>

  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS file:

```js
videojs.autoSetup();

videojs('my_video_1').ready(function() {
  console.log(this.options()); //log all of the default videojs options

  // Store the video object
  var myPlayer = this,
    id = myPlayer.id();
  // Make up an aspect ratio
  var aspectRatio = 264 / 640;

  function resizeVideoJS() {
    var width = document.getElementById(id).parentElement.offsetWidth;
    myPlayer.width(width).height(width * aspectRatio);

  }

  // Initialize resizeVideoJS()
  resizeVideoJS();
  // Then on resize call resizeVideoJS()
  window.onresize = resizeVideoJS;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a very old version of Video.js which doesn't support streaming formats without additional components. If you upgrade to v7.x (currently 7.8.2) it includes HLS and DASH support by default. The `type` attributes should also be corrected to `application/x-mpegURL` and `application/dash+xml` so they are handled as the right format.